# Inventory Tracking

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to see why my code isn't working. I'm guessing this is where I'm trying to get the `Address` of a cell. But what I'm trying to do is basically, if two data cells match the input cells then it would return true and grab the cell right of the two data cells and save that value as an integer that later gets added to the cell of the input.

```vb
Sub add()
    Dim ItemCode As String
    Dim Size As String
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim CodeMatch As Boolean
    Dim SizeMatch As Boolean
    Dim CellOffsetMatch As Variant
    Dim OriginalCount As Object
    Dim Ranger As String

    Let Size = Range("Size2").Value
    Let Count = Range("count3").Value
    Let ItemCode = Range("Code2").Value
    Let CodeMatch = False
    Let SizeMatch = False
   
    For Each CodeCell In Worksheets("Inventory").Range("B2:B45")
        If CodeCell.Value = ItemCode Then CodeMatch = True
    Next
    
    For Each SizeCell In Worksheets("Inventory").Range("C2:C45")
         If SizeCell.Value = Size Then SizeMatch = True
         Set CellOffsetMatch = SizeCell.Address(
         Set OriginalCount = CellOffsetMatch.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next    

     If (CodeMatch = True And SizeMatch = True) Then
        Range("CellOffsetMatch").Offset(0, 1).Value = OriginalCount + Count
     Else
        MsgBox "Sorry Looks like the Item you input is not in Inventory. Try Again or use the 'Count' button to add it"
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing the right parenthesis in the following line Set CellOffsetMatch = SizeCell.Address(  .Address() is the right syntaxis.

Comment: Getting the address of the `SizeCell`? Remove the parenthesis at the end of `.Address`, and remove the word `Set` as `.Address` is a `String`, but you can use `Variant` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to tell exactly what you're trying to do here, but I've made a few assumptions along the way and the following code might be what you're looking for:

```
Sub add()
    Dim ItemCode As String
    Dim Size As String
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim CodeMatch As Boolean
    Dim SizeMatch As Boolean
    Dim CellOffsetMatch As String
    Dim OriginalCount As Long
    Dim Ranger As String

    Let Size = Range("Size2").Value
    Let Count = Range("count3").Value
    Let ItemCode = Range("Code2").Value
    Let CodeMatch = False
    Let SizeMatch = False
    
    With Worksheets("Inventory")
    
        For Each CodeCell In .Range("B2:B45")
            If CodeCell.Value = ItemCode Then CodeMatch = True
        Next
        
        For Each SizeCell In .Range("C2:C45")
             If SizeCell.Value = Size Then
                SizeMatch = True
                CellOffsetMatch = SizeCell.Address
                OriginalCount = .Range(CellOffsetMatch).Offset(0, 1).Value
             End If
        Next
    
         If (CodeMatch = True And SizeMatch = True) Then
            .Range(CellOffsetMatch).Offset(0, 1).Value = OriginalCount + Count
         Else
            MsgBox "Sorry Looks like the Item you input is not in Inventory. Try Again or use the 'Count' button to add it"
         End If
         
     End With
     
End Sub
```

All that being said, looking at your search logic it will cause issues if the Code is present but a different code with a matching size is then found. They shouldn't be independent checks. I would suggest this might work better:

```
Sub add()
    Dim ItemCode As String
    Dim Size As String
    Dim count As Long
    Dim CodeCell As Variant  
    Dim CellOffsetMatch As String

    Let Size = Range("Size2").Value
    Let count = Range("count3").Value
    Let ItemCode = Range("Code2").Value
    
    With Worksheets("Inventory")
    
        CellOffsetMatch = ""
        
        For Each CodeCell In .Range("B2:B45")
            If CodeCell.Value = ItemCode And CodeCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Size Then CellOffsetMatch = CodeCell.Offset(0, 1).Address
        Next
        
        If CellOffsetMatch <> "" Then
           .Range(CellOffsetMatch).Offset(0, 1).Value = .Range(CellOffsetMatch).Offset(0, 1).Value + count
        Else
           MsgBox "Sorry Looks like the Item you input is not in Inventory. Try Again or use the 'Count' button to add it"
        End If
         
     End With
     
End Sub
```